# How Can I Add A Column to my DataFrame That Shows Which Businesses Have a Social Media Presence and Which Businesses Do Not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataset that holds information relating to businesses in the City of Brampton. Several variables in my dataframe show the social media accounts of the respective businesses. The null values represent businesses that don't have a social media presence on a particular platform: YouTube, LinkedIn, etc.

I would like to create an additional column in my dataframe which shows the businesses that have a social media presence. A value of 0 should indicate that the business does not have a social media presence and a value of 1 should indicate that the business does have a social media presence.

[image: The left side of the head of the dataframe]

[image: The right side of the head of the dataframe]

I've also included a link to the dataset [here](http://geohub.brampton.ca/datasets/brampton-business-directory)

Frankly, I have zero clue how to tackle this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Its a duplicate question, you can try df['new'] = df[['FACEBOOK', 'TWITTER','LINKEDIN','INSTAGRAM']].notnull(1).astype(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `HasSocialMedia = True` if one of Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, YouTube or Instagram is not null:

```
df['HasSocialMedia'] = df[['FACEBOOK', 'TWITTER', 'LINKEDIN', 'YOUTUBE', 'INSTAGRAM']].any(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.